Seeking Advice on Measuring Sleep Deprivation for Research
I'm working on a research study exploring the relationship between sleep deprivation and academic performance among accountancy students. We're using a Likert scale to measure academic performance and would like to maintain consistency by measuring sleep deprivation in the same way.
Could you recommend any existing tools, or suggest how we could adapt sleep deprivation measures into a Likert scale format?

You came to the right place; most of us are sleep-deprived here. (Peter's answer is very useful too. (+1))

Beware that self-reporting is especially fraught for sleep deprivation. One of the symptoms of extreme deprivation is feeling especially awake!

First, I know of no reason that you should want to measure all your variables in the same way.
Second, I'm not sure why you are measuring academic performance on a Likert scale. The usual measure is grade point average. If you are comparing various universities, there are ways to adjust. You could also look at grade on a particular test, and sleep deprivation on that same day.
Third, if you do want to measure sleep deprivation on a Likert scale, you could look at a question such as "How sleepy do you get during the day?"  The good thing about this is that it accounts for the fact that different people need different amounts of sleep. The bad thing is that, like many Likert type tests, it is subjective.
Finally, although you didn't ask about it, I am wondering about your research design. Are you measuring sleep deprivation at multiple times? Just before an exam? I think there could be some interesting questions here such as the effect of being sleep deprived for the semester, but getting sleep the night before the test vs. pulling an all nighter right before the exam. There might also be curivlinear effects, which argues against a Likert scale for sleep deprivation. I know there is a non-monotonic relationship between stress and grades, with a modest amount of stress being related to the best grades (some students have so little stress that they don't study, maybe even get drunk or stoned the night before; on the other end, some get so stressed that they can barely remember their names).
